# Why does quarkus use hibernate reactive to operate the database and the query method does not use database connection pool

Tags: quarkus, hibernate-reactive

I use the quarkus framework, integrate hibernate reactive, and use the panache list method to query. I find that it do not use the connection pool, but use the connection directly. As a result, the query cannot be used after the connection is closed.

SqlClientConnection

```java
public CompletionStage<RowSet<Row>> preparedQuery(String sql, Tuple parameters) {
        feedback(sql);
        String processedSql = usePostgresStyleParameters ? Parameters.process( sql, parameters.size() ) : sql;
        return Handlers.toCompletionStage(
                        handler -> client().preparedQuery( processedSql ).execute( parameters, handler )
        );
}
```

PanacheQueryImpl

```java
  @Override
    public <T extends Entity> Uni<List<T>> list() {
        return delegate.list();
    }
```

I'd like to know how to use pool when querying?

Answer (score 1):

Technically it doesn't need a traditional connection pool, because all operations are non-blocking, so you can easily saturate your CPU completely with a single connection to the database.

In practice the default is to use a single connection for each Vert.x context, and by default you'll have two such contexts per CPU.

When you say "query cannot be used after the connection is closed" I suspect you're actually hitting a bug we fixed recently; please add more details to a new question; I suspect the solution for your issue (in that case) is that you need to use Panache Reactive from a non-blocking context, such as using RESTEasy Reactive for your endpoint.

Comment: Panache Reactive sounds interesting. Is there an extension for oracle db as well?

Comment: Not yet, the Oracle SQL client is expected to first appear in vert.x 4.2; it's not  released yet. (that's the component we need to have a high performance reactive replacement for the JDBC driver)

Comment: thanks for you reply. I am really looking forward to it. Is there a place where i can follow the progress on it? (eg. A roadmap?)

Comment: The project is fully open: https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client , https://vertx.io/ . There's chats and mailing lists. I hope to see you there :)